# Send data from Lightning Web Component (LWC) to a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

I am adding an LWC component in visualforce and need to add a handler for an event fired in the LWC component on the visualforce page.
When googling all I can find is examples of how to do this with aura component using application events.

LWC controller:

```js
handleSearchClick() {
        
    const searchinfo = { 
        shipper: this.shipper,
        system: this.system,
        product: this.product,
        status: this.template.querySelector('c-lwc-multi-select').value(),
        period: this.period  
    };
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(
        'dosearch', 
        {
            detail: { data:  searchinfo},
            bubbles: true,
            composed: true,
        }
    ));
    console.log({ 'lwcNominationSearch searchinfo': searchinfo });
}
```

AURA app:

```xml
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="GLOBAL">
<aura:dependency resource="c:lwcNominationSearch" />
<aura:dependency resource="markup://force:*" type="EVENT"/>
</aura:application>
```

Visualforce:

```html
<div id="rcontainer">
</div>

<script>
    $Lightning.use("c:NotificationSearch_ltngoutApp", function()
    {
        $Lightning.createComponent(
        "c:lwcNominationSearch",
        {},
        "rcontainer",
        function(cmp)
        {
            console.log('component created');
             //$A.eventService.addHandler({ "event": "c:myEvent", "handler" : visualForceFunction})
              $A.eventService.addHandler({
                event: 'dosearch',
                handler: function (event) {

                        console.log("vf event success");
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I figured out how to make it work by wrapping the LWC component in a aura component but it would be cleaner to not have to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You implemented correctly in LWC of dispatching event. However callback function is not meant for adding some event handlers. You should add event listener directly. Below is the code with changes needed in vf page:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("dosearch", function(event){
    console.log('vf event data window listener => ', event.detail);
});

$Lightning.use("c:NotificationSearch_ltngoutApp", function() {
    $Lightning.createComponent("c:lwcNominationSearch",
                               {},
                               "rcontainer",
                               function(cmp) {}
                              );
});
</script>
```

Comment: salesforce-sas Thank you this was exacly what I needed.

Comment: This helped me too. But how to send it from Vf page to LWC. I cant use LMS

Comment: @NBR user below link for Visualforce to LWC method call
https://techdicer.com/call-lwc-method-from-visualforce-page/

Answer (score 1):

For a full compilation of what is needed. My use case uses openCTI that uses a Lightning out adapter.

VF Page

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/support/api/51.0/lightning/opencti.js"></script>
   
    <div id="lightning"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $Lightning.use("c:sampleOut", function () {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:sampleLWC",
                {},
                "lightning",
                function (cmp) {

                    document.querySelector('c-sample-lwc').addEventListener('samplemessage', (e) => {
                        client.call(e.detail);
                    });

                    console.log(document.querySelector('c-sample-lwc').dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('sampleresponse', {detail: 'Message Received'})));
                });
        });

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

AuraAdapter : sampleOut.app

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp"  access="GLOBAL" description="The Lightning Out app which hosts the cti adapter." >
    <aura:dependency resource="c:sampleLWC"/>
</aura:application>
```

Lightning Component: sampleLWC.js

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class sampleLWC extends LightningElement {
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener("sampleresponse", (e) => {
      console.log(e.detail);
    });
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.dispatchEvent(
      new CustomEvent("samplemessage", {
        detail: "Hurry! the British are coming."
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Winter ’20 release, you can use Lightning message service. This is an example:
http://www.webuildsf.cloud/salesforce-crm/an-example-to-communicate-between-lightning-web-components-and-visualforce-pages/

Comment: Sadly not available for Lightning out yet.

Comment: :( so many things not available for Lightning out .

Comment: @manhnk.bkit you actually don't need this. See my answer below.