# Send data from Visualforce page to Lightning Web Component (LWC)

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components

I have similar situation and have used this answer
[Send data from Lightning Web Component (LWC) to a Visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/278059/send-data-from-lightning-web-component-lwc-to-a-visualforce-page/278063#278063?newreg=3f37828851f0417899b7e3fff4e77b66) from @salesforce-sas which worked perfectly for me.

Now I have the problem in the other direction - that is sending data through an event from VF Page -> Aura App -> LWC.

I see some ideas on this but nothing that solves this specific issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use Lightning Message Service for communication across VF page, lightning and LWC.

Try with example mentioned in release notes

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_message_channel.htm